# Find an orientation preserving isometry $f (z) = \frac{az+b}{cz+d}$ such that $f (i) = 17 + 3i$

Tags: geometry, complex-analysis, transformation

[image]

This is probably a very simple questions but I am not clear on Möbius transformations and how to solve this problem. I'd appreciate if somebody can point me towards a method to do these sort of questions or a webpage that explains what I need to solve this problem.

Comment: you could just use a linear map, $f(z)=3z+17$ for instance

Answer (score 1):

Consider $f(z)=3z+17$. It sends $i$ to $17+3i$ as desired and also preserves orientation since it is a polynomial over $z$ and hence a holomorphic function.

Edit: As "yoyo" already stated in the comments... I was being careless to see the comment.

Comment: Thank you! I'd like to read more about polynomials over z preserving orientation and holomorphic functions because I don't understand those yet. Any specific sources you suggest ?

Comment: I meant to say all polynomials are holomorphic functions which are orientation preserving maps. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holomorphic_function

Answer (score 1):

When you use the word "isometry" you have to indicate the exact domain that should be mapped and the used metric(s) on the domain and codomain.

If you have just  ${\mathbb C}$ with its euclidean metric in mind the simplest Möbius transformation mapping the point $i$ to $17+3i$ would be the translation $f:\ z\mapsto z+c$ with translation vector $c=17+2i$.